# Appending a char to a string in rust

Tags: rust, traits

The documentation [here](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.10/std/str/trait.OwnedStr.html) defines a trait which, among other things, has a method `push_char` which takes a mutable `self` and appends a character to it. However, this code fails:

```
fn foo() {
  let mut s = "hey".to_owned();
  s.push_char('!');
}
```

Attempting to compile this:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.11-pre (e8053b9 2014-05-12 09:12:04 -0700)
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
$ rustc appendchar.rs
appendchar.rs:5:5: 5:19 error: type `~str` does not implement any method in scope named `push_char`
appendchar.rs:5   s.push_char('!');
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So we can see that `s` is indeed of type `~str`, and according to the docs, this type implements `OwnedStr`. So why does this fail? By the way, adding the following line doesn't solve it:

```
use std::str::OwnedStr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are using 0.10 documentation and a master build. In preparation for the brave new world of Dynamically Sized Types, where `~str` (a.k.a. `Box<str>`) does not contain a *capacity* but only a *length* and thus cannot efficiently be pushed to as it would require reallocating every single time, [those methods have been removed from `OwnedStr`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/trait.OwnedStr.html). Now you should be dealing with [`StrBuf`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/strbuf/struct.StrBuf.html) instead, which has the methods like `push_char`.